# Возможно ли в ECMAScript 6 создать переменную (не аксессор) в теле класса?

Tags: javascript

Можно как-то создать переменную в теле класса не считая get\set?

Answer (score 2):

Вы имеете ввиду альтернативу

```
function  myClass() {
// costructor 
}

myClass.prototype.property = "test";
```

?

в виде

```
class myClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.property);
  }
  a: "property";
}
```

нет, т.к.

[Inside the body of a class definition
A class body can only contain methods, but not data properties. Prototypes having data properties is generally considered an anti-pattern, so this just enforces a best practice.](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html)

вы, конечно можете объявить это через prototype, как в первом примере, но вызов super.property вернет неожиданный результат.

В ES7, возможно, это будет реализовано.